# In $\mathbb{C}$, prove that $z_1z_2z_3=0 \Rightarrow z_1=0$ or $z_2=0$ or $z_3=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I could prove this but I'd like to see other ways.

My prove was something like (by contrapositive):

Suppose they are all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{C}$, hence they have their inverses. And now, suppose that could be the case that $z_1z_2z_3=0$, but then $ 0=z_2^{-1}z_1^{-1}z_1z_2z_3=z_3 $, contradiction.

I am asking myself if this could be provedd by using the definition of multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$, so I'd like to see other proofs for this.

What are your ideas?

Comment: You could use the fact that if the product of two complex numbers is $0$ then one of them must be $0$. But proving that is probably done the way you proved your theorem for the product of three numbers.

Comment: If you take a more general look, you can prove it for $n$ numbers by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $z=0$ if and only if $|z|=0$. Therefore
$$z_1z_2z_3=0\Leftrightarrow |z_1z_2z_3|=0\Leftrightarrow |z_1||z_2||z_3|=0\Rightarrow |z_1|=0\hspace{0.1cm}\text{or}\hspace{0.1cm}|z_2|=0\hspace{0.1cm}\text{or}\hspace{0.1cm}|z_3|=0$$
if and only if $z_1=0$ or $z_2=0$ or $z_3=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In any field $K$, $z_1\cdots z_n=0$ implies that one of the $z_i$ is zero, because a field has no nontrivial zero divisors. So this does not depend on the complex numbers, but holds in general.

Comment: It's unclear, but the question may be about proving that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field via the definition of multiplication on it and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field.